# does openCL support vectors as kernel arguments?

Tags: c++, kernel, opencl, opencl-c

I've been thinking of ways to rewrite this code in openCL kernel form. It won't be particularly hard to convert (getting rid of glm types and bit masking), but the part I'm stuck on is how to pass the `_triangles`, `_uvs`, `_indices`, and `_normals` to the kernel. Is there any built-in functionality for vectors in openCL?

The only option I see, if there isn't any vector support, would be to pass 4 arrays of type `float3` for each of the 3 variables I need to be returned (`_triangles`, `_uvs`, and `_normals`) and 2 arrays of `float3` for `_indices`. Then in CPU convert the arrays back to vectors and shrink them to fit. I'm not so sure that passing so many memory buffers to the kernel is an efficient way to go through because that would be 14 arrays passed and returned from the kernel. Other solutions I have won't work when parallelized. Is there a way to simplify this solution, or better yet a purely better solution?

The function I have trouble with is `_addRectangle` and `_createMesh` is the function it will be combined within the kernel.

```
void Chunk::_addRectangle(glm::vec3 center, glm::vec3 height, glm::vec3 width, unsigned tex_num, cl_uint LOD)
{
    glm::vec3 corner1 = center - (height / 2.0) - (width / 2.0);
    glm::vec3 corner2 = center - (height / 2.0) + (width / 2.0);
    glm::vec3 corner3 = center + (height / 2.0) + (width / 2.0);
    glm::vec3 corner4 = center + (height / 2.0) - (width / 2.0);

    glm::vec3 normal = glm::cross(height, width);

    glm::vec2 uv1;
    glm::vec2 uv2;
    glm::vec2 uv3;
    glm::vec2 uv4;

    if (fabs(normal[1]) == 1.0)
    {
        uv1 = glm::vec2(1.0 / _tex_atlas_width, 1);
        uv2 = glm::vec2(1.0 / _tex_atlas_width, 0);
        uv3 = glm::vec2(0, 0);
        uv4 = glm::vec2(0, 1);
    }
    else
    {
        uv1 = glm::vec2(1.0 / _tex_atlas_width, 1);
        uv2 = glm::vec2(1.0 / _tex_atlas_width, 0);
        uv3 = glm::vec2(0, 0);
        uv4 = glm::vec2(0, 1);
    }

    float add = (1.0 / double(_tex_atlas_width)) * tex_num;
    uv1.x += add;
    uv2.x += add;
    uv3.x += add;
    uv4.x += add;

    // triangle 1
    _triangles.push_back(corner3);
    _triangles.push_back(corner2);
    _triangles.push_back(corner1);

    _normals.push_back(normal);
    _normals.push_back(normal);
    _normals.push_back(normal);

    _uvs.push_back(uv1);
    _uvs.push_back(uv2);
    _uvs.push_back(uv3);

    _indices.push_back(glm::ivec3(nrOfIndices + 0, nrOfIndices + 1, nrOfIndices + 2));

    // triangle 2 

    _triangles.push_back(corner4);
    _normals.push_back(normal);
    _uvs.push_back(uv4);


    _indices.push_back(glm::ivec3(nrOfIndices + 2, nrOfIndices + 3, nrOfIndices + 0));
    nrOfIndices += 4;

}

void Chunk::_createMesh(glm::ivec3 pos, int landmap_flags[96 * 96 * 96], cl_int LOD)
{
    std::byte* faces = new std::byte[chunkSize / LOD * chunkSize / LOD * chunkSize / LOD];

    int index = 0;

    // a index conversion from a single index array to a 3d array
    // landmap_flags[x + y * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + z * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))] is

    for (int x = LOD; x < chunkSize + LOD; x += LOD) {
        for (int y = LOD; y < chunkSize + LOD; y += LOD) {
            for (int z = LOD; z < chunkSize + LOD; z += LOD) {
                x + y * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + z * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD));
                faces[index] = (std::byte)0;
                if (landmap_flags[x + y * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + z * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))] == BLOCK::AIR)
                {
                    index++;
                    continue;
                }
                if (landmap_flags[x + y * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + z * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))] != BLOCK::AIR)
                {
                    if (landmap_flags[(x - LOD) + y * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + z * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))] == BLOCK::AIR)
                        faces[index] |= (std::byte)Direction::South;
                    if (landmap_flags[(x + LOD) + y * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + z * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))] == BLOCK::AIR)
                        faces[index] |= (std::byte)Direction::North;
                    if (landmap_flags[x + (y - LOD) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + z * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))] == BLOCK::AIR)
                        faces[index] |= (std::byte)Direction::Down;
                    if (landmap_flags[x + (y + LOD) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + z * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))] == BLOCK::AIR)
                        faces[index] |= (std::byte)Direction::Up;
                    if (landmap_flags[x + y * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + (z - LOD) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))] == BLOCK::AIR)
                        faces[index] |= (std::byte)Direction::West;
                    if (landmap_flags[x + y * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + (z + LOD) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))] == BLOCK::AIR)
                        faces[index] |= (std::byte)Direction::East;
                }

                if (faces[index] == (std::byte)0)
                    continue;

                if ((faces[index] & (std::byte)Direction::North) != (std::byte)0)
                {
                    _addRectangle(
                        glm::vec3( x + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.x) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2) + (float(LOD) / 2),
                                   y + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.y) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2),
                                   z + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.z) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2)),
                        glm::vec3(0, LOD, 0),
                        glm::vec3(0, 0, -LOD),
                        landmap_flags[x + y * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + z * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))],
                        LOD);
                }
                if ((faces[index] & (std::byte)Direction::East) != (std::byte)0)
                {
                    _addRectangle(
                        glm::vec3( x + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.x) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2),
                                   y + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.y) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2),
                                   z + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.z) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2) + (float(LOD) / 2)),
                        glm::vec3(0, LOD, 0),
                        glm::vec3(LOD, 0, 0),
                        landmap_flags[x + y * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + z * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))],
                        LOD);
                }
                if ((faces[index] & (std::byte)Direction::South) != (std::byte)0)
                {
                    _addRectangle(
                        glm::vec3( x + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.x) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2) - (float(LOD) / 2),
                                   y + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.y) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2),
                                   z + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.z) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2)),
                        glm::vec3(0, LOD, 0),
                        glm::vec3(0, 0, LOD),
                        landmap_flags[x + y * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + z * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))],
                        LOD);
                }
                if ((faces[index] & (std::byte)Direction::West) != (std::byte)0)
                {
                    _addRectangle(
                        glm::vec3( x + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.x) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2),
                                   y + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.y) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2),
                                   z + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.z) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2) - (float(LOD) / 2)),
                        glm::vec3(0, LOD, 0),
                        glm::vec3(-LOD, 0, 0),
                        landmap_flags[x + y * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + z * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))],
                        LOD);
                }
                if ((faces[index] & (std::byte)Direction::Up) != (std::byte)0)
                {
                    _addRectangle(
                        glm::vec3( x + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.x) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2),
                                   y + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.y) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2) + (float(LOD) / 2),
                                   z + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.z) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2)),
                        glm::vec3(LOD, 0, 0),
                        glm::vec3(0, 0, LOD),
                        landmap_flags[x + y * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + z * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))],
                        LOD);
                }
                if ((faces[index] & (std::byte)Direction::Down) != (std::byte)0)
                {
                    _addRectangle(
                        glm::vec3( x + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.x) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2),
                                   y + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.y) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2) - (float(LOD) / 2),
                                   z + ((chunkSize - 1) * pos.z) - (chunkSize / 2) - (float(LOD - 1) / 2)),
                        glm::vec3(LOD, 0, 0),
                        glm::vec3(0, 0, -LOD),
                        landmap_flags[x + y * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) + z * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD)) * (chunkSize + (2 * LOD))],
                        LOD);
                }
                index++;
            }
        }
    }

    delete[]faces;
}
```

Thank you!

Edit: A possible more efficient way of storing the data would be in several float4 types.
e.g.:

```
const uint n = get_global_id(0);

float4 triangles{1, 2, 3, 4}; // calculated values for each vertex

//(float4 list[size];) from constructor
list[n] = triangles;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `OpenCL` there are vector types like `float4`, etc. More on this can be read [here](https://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1732873&seqNum=3).
There aren't containers like `std::vector` in `c++` so the data must be passed using C-style arrays.

Looking at the part of the code in the question, `_triangles`, `_uvs`, `_indices`, and `_normals` would be filled with results so the appropriate buffers would need to be allocated and passed to the kernel in order to store the results and read them back after kernel finishes its work.

Passing 14 arrays shouldn't be an issue as long as the kernel is enough computationally intensive and looking at the code it might be as there are 2 nested loops. But it looks like a lot depends on how big are `chunkSize` and `LOD` variables. You would need to try it out and see how it performs.

There shouldn't be any issue with copying data back to `std::vector` - just use `memcpy`.

Comment: Note that the `data()` of a `std::vector` **can** be passed to OpenCL if you use `CL_MEM_USE_HOST_PTR` during buffer creation, but except on shared-memory devices this is likely to either yield poor performance, or to data being copied to device memory regardless. Plus, you have to worry about lifetime and avoiding host-side access during device access.

Comment: Also, ```_triangles```, ```_uvs```, ```_indices```, and ```_normals``` must be in a certain order to be rendered properly by openGL, so memcpy might not work since all of the arrays are condensed, but the vectors would need to contain the data in the same chronologically set order that the function has.

Comment: @HeartUnder8lade If you're using the output data directly in OpenGL, why not use OpenCL-OpenGL bridging to write directly to one or more OpenGL vertex/index array buffers from your OpenCL kernel?

Comment: @pmdj I didn't realize this existed, do you have a link for any documentation or code examples on this?